# Using IN with LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

OK I have a question to which an answer might be simple but im not sure how to do it:

**Question:**
How do i use IN with LIKE?

**Why Not Duplicate:**
Well I know if i have multiple strings i can use **OR** to check. But this is not the case with what i am trying to do.

**Question Explaination:**
I have an SP with a parameter @path, now i would like to send multiple paths, separated by delimiter, (to avoid calling sp multiple times). I split the string using a custom function which returns a table with splited values.
Now how would i go about using the values from that splited values table to be used with LIKE operator.

**What I have done so far:**

```
declare
    @path varchar(max) = 'CompanyRules/Billing/IntegrationServices|CompanyRules/Reports/IntegrationServices',
    @default_code varchar(max) = '1'

    declare @tempTable TABLE(path varchar(max))

    INSERT INTO @tempTable (path)
    SELECT split from fn_splitby(@path, '|')

    select prg.path, prg.default_code, prmd.optional_property_1, prmd.optional_property_2, prmd.optional_property_3, prmd.optional_property_4, prmd.optional_property_5, prmd.optional_property_6
    from pdm_rule_group prg, pdi_rule_master prmd
    where prg.path = prmd.path
    AND prg.path in (select path from @tempTable)
    AND prg.default_code != @default_code
```

The this will not yield any result.

**Possible Solution:**
What i though was that i have to loop through the @tempTable and then create separate strings to be used with LIKE. Which im sure is a bad solution, and may have some other solution to it.

Comment: "to avoid calling sp multiple times" - then use an appropriate data structure - a table-valued parameter. Don't stuff everything into a `varchar(max)` just to then have to unpack it again inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace this statement

```
AND prg.path in (select path from @tempTable)
```

with

```
AND EXISTS (select 1 from @tempTable where   prg.path  like "%"+path+"%" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join to the table:

```
select prg.path, prg.default_code, prmd.optional_property_1, prmd.optional_property_2, prmd.optional_property_3, prmd.optional_property_4, prmd.optional_property_5, prmd.optional_property_6
from
   pdm_rule_group prg
     inner join
   pdi_rule_master prmd
     on prg.path = prmd.path
     inner join
   @tempTable tt
     on
        prg.path like tt.path
where 
    prg.default_code != @default_code
```